# connect bluetooth audio in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

I am connecting to bluetooth speaker with ubuntu (15.04) on command line.
I can scan and pair up the speaker with

```
hcitool scan
bt-device -c <mac address>
```

but when I connect with the following command, there is an error.

```
bt-audio -c <mac address>
org.bluez.Error.Failed: Connect Failed
```

and later I found out these log appear in /var/log

```
Unable to select SEP
bluetoothd[588]: Unable to select SEP
```

Anyone know the solution?